# Running a Perl script as cronjob is not working while manual starting does the job

Tags: 14.04, scripts, backup, cron, perl

I have 3 cronjob entries (`crontab -l`) the first entry is a Perl script what creates a LVM backup of a virtual machine and the other two are just sh files performing `mysqldump`.

Well however, I edited `crontab -e` as root (`sudo su` first) and this is my first job entry

```
# Run daily backup of my job at 3:15 [relation ä11]
15 3 * * * perl /opt/AUTO_BACKUP/virt-backup.pl --action=dump --date --vm=SERVER2
```

Well but it neither creates any output in the backup directory nor any entries in the cron logs. In the cron log files I found only entries of the other sh jobs.

But when I copy the command `perl /opt/AUTO_BACKUP/virt-backup.pl --action=dump --date --vm=SERVER2` right into the root terminal it works like a charm. So since I edit `crontab` as root only the right user should run the job. And also no errors in log.

Comment: I have my cronjobs log to a file so I can review the results. If you append something like this: **[mycronjob.sh] >> /var/log/mycronjob.log 2>&1** It should write output and errors to the file shown, and then you can review the errors that are occurring.

Comment: Thank you, now I got a error, may have missed it in the previous log.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `perl` entry to `path/to/perl`. Often times, commands such as `perl` and `python` are actually environment based things and are found in your PATH. As cron lacks that PATH, it's best to use absolute paths in crontab.

Comment: Thanks, I already was playing with that possibility. I will give it a try and give feedback tomorrow. :)

Comment: Meanwhile I found an error. I set perl to /usr/bin/perl so that works well.

But in the script appears following problem

`Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /opt/AUTO_BACKUP/virt-backup.pl line 147.
Can't find lvremove`

Assuming to the point that the script is working without cron the `.` concatenation isn’t the problem but the fact that it can not find lvremove.

Maybe another environment variable problem?
Is there a way that I pass my regular env. settings to the script when called by cron?

Comment: You could wrap the Perl script within a shell script that exports everything that your ~/.profile file does.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the script runs when being executed from the shell but not as a cronjob is usually the different env it finds there.

So change your cronjob to save the env in e.g. /tmp/env by using

```
env | sort> /tmp/env
```

and when /tmp/env arrives diff it with your current env.

```
env | sort | diff - /tmp/env
```

HTH